# Using JavaScript function in Java: exception

Tags: javascript, java, exception

I am trying to use a JavaScript function I wrote in my Java code.

My Java code looks like this:

```java
public class JSTest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, NoSuchMethodException, IOException {
        ScriptEngineManager scriptManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        // Read script file
        scriptEngine.eval(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("/Users/jonaseveraert/Documents/maven_library_test/src/main/java/javascriptFunction.js"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // Exception happens here

        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) scriptEngine;
        Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("encodeerMorse", "sos");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

So it executes the encodeerMorse function, stores the result in an Object and prints it.

My JavaScript function looks like this:

```js
function encodeerMorse(input) {
    var output = "";

    input = input.toUpperCase();
    var inputAsCharArray = Array.from(input);
    var previousChar = ' ';
    inputAsCharArray.forEach(char => {
        var encodedChar; // this is where the exception happen
        switch (char) {
            case 'A':
                encodedChar = ".- ";
                break;
            case 'B':
                encodedChar = "-... ";
                break;
            case 'C':
                encodedChar = "-... ";
                break;
            case 'D':
                encodedChar = "-.. ";
                break;
            case 'Ë':
            case 'E':
                encodedChar = ". ";
                break;
            case 'F':
                encodedChar = "..-. ";
                break;
            case 'G':
                encodedChar = "--. ";
                break;
            case 'H':
                encodedChar = ".... ";
                break;
            case 'I':
                encodedChar = ".. ";
                break;
            case 'J':
                encodedChar = ".--- ";
                break;
            case 'K':
                encodedChar = "-.- ";
                break;
            case 'L':
                encodedChar = ".-.. ";
                break;
            case 'M':
                encodedChar = "-- ";
                break;
            case 'N':
                encodedChar = "-. ";
                break;
            case 'O':
                encodedChar = "--- ";
                break;
            case 'P':
                encodedChar = ".--. ";
                break;
            case 'Q':
                encodedChar = "--.- ";
                break;
            case 'R':
                encodedChar = ".-. ";
                break;
            case 'S':
                encodedChar = "... ";
                break;
            case 'T':
                encodedChar = "- ";
                break;
            case 'U':
                encodedChar = "..- ";
                break;
            case 'V':
                encodedChar = "...- ";
                break;
            case 'W':
                encodedChar = ".-- ";
                break;
            case 'X':
                encodedChar = "-..- ";
                break;
            case 'Y':
                encodedChar = "-.-- ";
                break;
            case 'Z':
                encodedChar = "--.. ";
                break;
            case '0':
                encodedChar = "----- ";
                break;
            case '1':
                encodedChar = ".---- ";
                break;
            case '2':
                encodedChar = "..--- ";
                break;
            case '3':
                encodedChar = "...-- ";
                break;
            case '4':
                encodedChar = "....- ";
                break;
            case '5':
                encodedChar = "..... ";
                break;
            case '6':
                encodedChar = "-.... ";
                break;
            case '7':
                encodedChar = "--... ";
                break;
            case '8':
                encodedChar = "---.. ";
                break;
            case '9':
                encodedChar = "----. ";
                break;
            case '.':
                encodedChar = ".-.-.- ";
                break;
            case ',':
                encodedChar = "--..-- ";
                break;
            case '?':
                encodedChar = "..--.. ";
                break;
            case '!':
                encodedChar = "-.-.-- ";
                break;
            case '-':
                encodedChar = "-....- ";
                break;
            case '/':
                encodedChar = "-..-. ";
                break;
            case ':':
                encodedChar = "---... ";
                break;
            case "'":
                encodedChar = ".----. ";
            case ')':
                encodedChar = "-.--.- "
                break;
            case ';':
                encodedChar = "-.-.- ";
                break;
            case '(':
                encodedChar = "-.--. ";
                break;
            case '=':
                encodedChar = "-...- ";
                break;
            case '@':
                encodedChar = ".--.-. ";
                break;
            case '&':
                encodedChar = ".-... ";
                break;
            case 'À':
            case 'Å':
                encodedChar = ".--.- ";
                break;
            case 'Ä':
            case 'Æ':
                encodedChar = ".-.- ";
                break;
            case 'Ç':
                encodedChar = "-.-.. ";
                break;
            case 'É':
                encodedChar = "..-.. ";
                break;
            case 'È':
                encodedChar = ".-..- ";
                break;
            case 'Ñ':
                encodedChar = "--.-- ";
                break;
            case 'Ö':
            case 'Ø':
                encodedChar = "---. ";
                break;
            case 'Ü':
                encodedChar = "..-- ";
                break;
            case '"':
                encodedChar = ".-..-. ";
                break;
            case ' ':
                encodedChar = "/ ";
                break;
            case '↵':
            case '\n':
                encodedChar = "<br/>";
                break;
            case '':
                encodedChar = "...---... ";
                break;
            case '':
            case '':
            case '':
                encodedChar = "...--... ";
                break;
            default:
                encodedChar = char;
        }

        // Save the encoded char
        if (previousChar != ' ')
            output += "/" + encodedChar;
        else output += encodedChar;

        previousChar = char;
    });

    return output;
}
```

When I run my Java code, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:8:12 Expected : but found encodedChar
        var encodedChar;
            ^ in <eval> at line number 8 at column number 12
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:537)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:150)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:249)
    at JSTest2.main(JSTest2.java:16)
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ParserException: <eval>:8:12 Expected : but found encodedChar
        var encodedChar;
            ^
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:294)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.error(AbstractParser.java:279)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expectDontAdvance(AbstractParser.java:350)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.AbstractParser.expect(AbstractParser.java:337)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.propertyAssignment(Parser.java:2297)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.objectLiteral(Parser.java:2155)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.primaryExpression(Parser.java:1988)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.memberExpression(Parser.java:2511)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.leftHandSideExpression(Parser.java:2372)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3147)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expression(Parser.java:3325)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.assignmentExpression(Parser.java:3353)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.argumentList(Parser.java:2588)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.leftHandSideExpression(Parser.java:2375)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.unaryExpression(Parser.java:3147)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expression(Parser.java:3282)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.expressionStatement(Parser.java:1150)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:967)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionBody(Parser.java:2901)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.functionExpression(Parser.java:2663)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.statement(Parser.java:875)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.sourceElements(Parser.java:773)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.program(Parser.java:709)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:283)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:249)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1284)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535)
    ... 5 more
```

The JavaScript function works when I use it on my website, but in Java it doesn't and I don't understand what the exception means.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Comment: ... What version of Java? Did you try it w/o an arrow function?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am using Java 8. I would like to know if this is possible with the array function, otherwise I a `for (var i = 0; i < inputAsCharArry.length; i++)` does seem to work

Comment: "The array function"? I asked if you'd tried it w/o an arrow function, which is a separate issue than `forEach`, if that's what you're referring to. I also assume you're aware that (a) Java 8 is... a bit old, (b) this is all deprecated as of Java 11, and (c) this is all gone as of Java 15. IIRC arrow functions were *proposed* for Java 9, but I don't recall if they made it in.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, I don't think I understood your question. Isn't the encodeerMorse function a regular function and not an arrow function?

Comment: @Jomy He's talking about the `char => {` "arrow" syntax for writing a lambda expression, which is likely not supported by the Nashorn engine in whatever version of Java you're using. Try changing it to regular `function (char) {` syntax.

Comment: Oh,  sorry about that. Yes, changing if to `function (char) {` fixed the problem. Thank you for that! I also had to change `Array.from(input)` to `input.split('')`.